# Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : cannot open the connection In addition: Warning message: In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :

Tags: r, mail-sender

Good morning, I am using R to send mass emails with the following code:

```
setwd("C:/Users/oscariro/Documents/R/Devoluciones")
tempreport <- file.path(getwd(),"Reenvio.rmd")
#file.copy("STC.Rmd",tempreport,overwrite = TRUE)
a=1
# Loop para enviar correo por

for(i in 1:nrow(Reenvia %>% select(cta_usuario) %>% distinct())){
  
  print(i)
  Asesor_<- Reenvia %>% select(cta_usuario) %>% distinct() %>% slice(i) %>% as.character()
  
  Nivelcc=Planta %>% filter(`FUERZA COMERCIAL`=="DIRECTOR") %>% filter(SBAN==Planta %>% filter(UsuarioCobis==Asesor_) %>%
                                                                         select(SBAN) %>% distinct() %>% as.character() ) %>%
    select(Correo) %>% distinct() %>% as.character()
  print("2a7")
  
  #nbcc="xxxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxx.xxxx.xx"
  
  
  parametros <- list(Comercial=Reenvia %>% filter(cta_usuario==Asesor_) %>% select(nombre_usuario) %>% distinct() %>% as.character(),
                     Asesor_=Asesor_)
  
  
  email<-blastula::render_email(input = tempreport,render_options = list(params=parametros))
  print(parametros$Comercial)
  # En caso de no poder enviar imprimir mensaje que no se pudo enviar correo
  tryCatch(
    email %>% smtp_send(
      from="xxxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxx.xxxx.xx",
      to=Planta %>% filter(UsuarioCobis==Asesor_) %>% select(Correo) %>% distinct() %>% as.character(),
      #to="xxxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxx.xxxx.xx",
      cc=Nivelcc,#bcc = nbcc,
      #cc="xxxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxx.xxxx.xx",
      #cc= c("xxxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxx.xxxx.xx","xxxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxx.xxxx.xx"),
      subject = glue("El motor de alertamientos te informa"),
      credentials=creds_key("outlook")
    ),error=function(e) {print(glue("No se le pudo enviar correo a {Asesor_}"))
      #a=rbind(a,Asesor_)
      #if(i==nrow(Alertas %>% select(Asesor) %>% distinct())){
      #openxlsx::write.xlsx(a,glue("{nrow(a)}_Usuarios que recibieron correo-{today()}"))
      #}
    }
  )
}
```

However, when shipment number 494 arrives, the shipment stops and the following error appears:

```
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open file 'alerta.knit.md': Too many open files
```